# No cache on rust-diesel

Tags: caching, rust, rust-diesel

I am using MySQL as my database, and diesel to retrieve the data. The data get updated every second from multiple end-points. The problem is while using diesel, to retrieve the data, the results I get are outdated (probably due to the cache on diesel side). MySQL runs with `SET GLOBAL query_cache_size = 0`, so there is no active cache on the DB server-side.

Here is the part of my code to retrieve the data:

```
pub struct Weather {
    pub id: u32,
    pub temperature: f32,
    pub datetime: NaiveDateTime,
}

pub fn {
    let timewindow = ... // A timewindow I set
    let results = weather.filter(datetime.ge(timewindow)).load::<Weather>(&db).unwrap();
    println("{:?}", results)
}
```

Do you know how I can deactivate the cache on diesel?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that shows the erratic behavior. To the best of my knowledge, diesel itself does not have a cache.

Comment: The problem is that I always retrieve the same results, although when I observe the DB the results have already been altered. Then after 1-2 minutes, I retrieve the new results. Afterward, nothing new comes from the DB. Then again after 1-2 mins new results, etc.

Comment: As one of the diesel maintainers I can tell you for sure: *There is no cache in diesel for query results*, this query just returns those data diesel gets back from the database. So this is either a problem with your query or a general setup problem.

Comment: Is there a way to perform something like that: `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id, name FROM customer;`?

Comment: Something like that is only possible via a raw `sql_query`.